# Using scalebox to decrease the size of listings code

Tags: beamer, listings

I want to the source code to fit in one frame because parts of it are out of the frame. But when I remove the comment in the following source code to use scalebox, I get something wrong. Here is my code and the output.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\mode<presentation>
{
  \usetheme{CambridgeUS}
  \usecolortheme{dolphin}
  \usecolortheme{rose}
  \setbeamerfont*{title}{shape=\itshape, family=\rmfamily}
  \setbeamercovered{transparent}
}
\let\Tiny\tiny
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{color}
\lstset{
  language=C,
  basicstyle=\footnotesize\ttfamily, 
  numbers=left,
  numberstyle=\footnotesize,
  stepnumber=1,
  tabsize=2,
  numbersep=-2pt,
  showspaces=false,
  showstringspaces=false,
  showtabs=false,
  frame=single,
  framexleftmargin=-10pt,
  captionpos=b,
  breaklines=true,
  breakatwhitespace=false,
  escapeinside={\%*}{*)}
}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile]
    \frametitle{Source code for static cache blocking}
    %\scalebox{0.8}{ % something wrong when I remove the comment to use scalebox
    \begin{lstlisting}
      void block_smvp_sparse (int r, int m,
          int *row_start, int *block_ptr,
          double *value, int *col_idx,
          double *src, double *dest)
      {
        int i, j;
        int b_i, b_j, b_m;
        int end_r;
        b_m = (m+r-1)/r;
        for (b_i=0; b_i<b_m; b_i++){
          end_r = (b_i+1 < b_m) ? r : m - b_i*r ;
          for (b_j=row_start[b_i]; b_j<row_start[b_i+1]; b_j+=end_r){
            for (i=0; i<end_r; i++){
              double t=0;
              for (j=block_ptr[b_j+i]; j<block_ptr[b_j+i+1]; j++)
                t += value[j] * src[col_idx[j]];
              dest[b_i*r+i] += t;
            }
          }
        }
      }
    \end{lstlisting}
      %}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Verbatim-like environments like `lstlisting` cannot be used as arguments of commands like `\scalebox`.

You can use a `lrbox` to create a box containing the `lstlisting` and then use it as the argument of `\scalebox`.

First of all, add

```
\newsavebox{\mybox}
```

in the preamble. Then embed the `lstlisting` in the `lrbox`

```
\begin{lrbox}{\mybox}%
    \begin{lstlisting}%
    .....
    \end{lstlisting}%
\end{lrbox}%
```

and finally print the scaled box

```
\scalebox{0.8}{\usebox{\mybox}}
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\mode<presentation>
{
  \usetheme{CambridgeUS}
  \usecolortheme{dolphin}
  \usecolortheme{rose}
  \setbeamerfont*{title}{shape=\itshape, family=\rmfamily}
  \setbeamercovered{transparent}
}
\let\Tiny\tiny
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{color}
\lstset{
  language=C,
  basicstyle=\footnotesize\ttfamily,
  numbers=left,
  numberstyle=\footnotesize,
  stepnumber=1,
  tabsize=2,
  numbersep=-2pt,
  showspaces=false,
  showstringspaces=false,
  showtabs=false,
  frame=single,
  framexleftmargin=-10pt,
  captionpos=b,
  breaklines=true,
  breakatwhitespace=false,
  escapeinside={\%*}{*)}
}

\newsavebox{\mybox}


\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile]
    \frametitle{Source code for static cache blocking}
\begin{lrbox}{\mybox}%
    \begin{lstlisting}%
      void block_smvp_sparse (int r, int m,
          int *row_start, int *block_ptr,
          double *value, int *col_idx,
          double *src, double *dest)
      {
        int i, j;
        int b_i, b_j, b_m;
        int end_r;
        b_m = (m+r-1)/r;
        for (b_i=0; b_i<b_m; b_i++){
          end_r = (b_i+1 < b_m) ? r : m - b_i*r ;
          for (b_j=row_start[b_i]; b_j<row_start[b_i+1]; b_j+=end_r){
            for (i=0; i<end_r; i++){
              double t=0;
              for (j=block_ptr[b_j+i]; j<block_ptr[b_j+i+1]; j++)
                t += value[j] * src[col_idx[j]];
              dest[b_i*r+i] += t;
            }
          }
        }
      }
    \end{lstlisting}%
\end{lrbox}%
\scalebox{0.8}{\usebox{\mybox}}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Output

[image]

Moreover, since I suspect that you want it centered horizontally in the frame, you can use

```
\begin{center}
\hspace*{1cm}\scalebox{0.8}{\usebox{\mybox}}
\end{center}
```

instead of simply

```
\scalebox{0.8}{\usebox{\mybox}}
```

and the result will be:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively to [karlkoeller answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/220725/37806), you can meanwhile use the [`minted`](https://ctan.org/pkg/minted?lang=en) package (which utilizes the powerful program [`pygments`](http://pygments.org/)). It offers the attribute `fontsize`, what is effectively what is done via `scalebox`.

The above code then reduces to:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\mode<presentation>
{
  \usetheme{CambridgeUS}
  \usecolortheme{dolphin}
  \usecolortheme{rose}
  \setbeamerfont*{title}{shape=\itshape, family=\rmfamily}
  \setbeamercovered{transparent}
}
\usepackage{minted}

% Adjust margin to display linenumbers
\setbeamersize{text margin left=2em}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile]

    \frametitle{Source code for static cache blocking}

    \begin{minted}[numbersep=5pt,
          frame=single,
          framesep=2pt,
          fontsize=\scriptsize,
          linenos,
          breaklines]{C}

      void block_smvp_sparse (int r, int m,
          int *row_start, int *block_ptr,
          double *value, int *col_idx,
          double *src, double *dest)
      {
        int i, j;
        int b_i, b_j, b_m;
        int end_r;
        b_m = (m+r-1)/r;
        for (b_i=0; b_i<b_m; b_i++){
          end_r = (b_i+1 < b_m) ? r : m - b_i*r ;
          for (b_j=row_start[b_i]; b_j<row_start[b_i+1]; b_j+=end_r){
            for (i=0; i<end_r; i++){
              double t=0;
              for (j=block_ptr[b_j+i]; j<block_ptr[b_j+i+1]; j++)
                t += value[j] * src[col_idx[j]];
              dest[b_i*r+i] += t;
            }
          }
        }
      }
    \end{minted}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

P.s.: Since `minted` utilizes an external program, it has to be compiled using the `-shell-escape` flag, e.g. `pdflatex -shell-escape beamercode.tex`